# Добавить дополнительный параметр в Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, как мне при выборе строки Продюсер передать в контроллер дополнительно еще одно значение string mode?

Вью:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Person", null, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "content"
            }, new { id = "ProducerSearch" }))
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("person", new SelectList(ViewBag.Producer, "person"), " ", new
                    {
                        @class = "form-control",
                        onchange = "AdditionalsChanged()",
                        style = "width: 150px",
                        id = "person"
                    })
                </div>
            }
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
    function AdditionalsChanged() {
        $('#ProducerSearch').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult Person(string name, string mode)
```

Comment: Ну ваще при передаче из формы можно не  указывать парметры котоыре передаются контролер. Например если у вас  в форме два input с именами input1 и input2 то в методе просто указать public ActionResult Person(string input1, string input2)

Comment: то списку просто задать имя и добавить параметр в контролер и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function AdditionalsChanged() {
    $('#ProducerSearch').append("<input type='hidden' name='mode' value='producer'/>");
    $('#ProducerSearch').submit();
}
```

Comment: не работает, показывает пустую страницу

Comment: @e1ement работает, Вы неправильно скопировали код

Comment: странно, точ в точ скопировал, но в блок <div id="content"> ничего не передает и он показывается мне пустым

Comment: в общем исправил и разделил методы, ну и проблема была в том, что не тот параметр передавал в метод. Спасибо.

Comment: не знаю но может input не показывает потомучто type='hidden'

Comment: нет, Игорь правильно все написал, это я в дроп листе указал Person вместо свойства которое надо вернуть Name... и сидел гадал почему все не так.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как бы так вроде

```
$("#person").change(function() {
    AdditionalsChanged();
});
```

ну можно так попробывать

```
public ActionResult Person(string name = "", string mode = "")
{

}
```

то есть параметры не обязательные

Comment: Смысл в том, что у меня 2 таких запроса, в первом рараметр actor, во втором producer

Comment: у них  один метод?

Comment: Да, метод один, использую ключ, по которому беру данные из разных таблиц

Comment: Я чет не понимаю проблемы  все равно

Comment: Т.е. в этом запросе должен передаваться по умолчанию параметр mode = "producer", чтобы его принял метод контроллера и обработал как ключ

Comment: Обновил ответ глянут

Comment: А как тогда метод поймёт кого ему подсунули искать?

Comment: Я не догоняю ты сразу два парметра передаеш или по 1.Он утебя принимает два но идет по 1 а 2 уже заранее по дефолту будет

Comment: Зачем такой геморой сделай 2 метода дял поиска по разным параметрам

Comment: Подумал и решил из 2х моделей сделать одну, и не надо будет доп ключей